Why does Athena report "The specified key does not exist" when inserting to an Iceberg table?
I'm creating an Iceberg table in Athena like this:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (`col1` string, `col2` string) 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/path/table1/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('table_type'='ICEBERG', 'format'='parquet')

and then trying to insert values into that table, like this:
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('hello', 'iceberg')

I'm encountering an error like this:

GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR:
io.trino.hdfs.s3.TrinoS3FileSystem$UnrecoverableS3OperationException:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
The specified key does not
exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ...

What am I doing wrong?

A fix for this will be rolled out soon, if it's not already happened. In the meantime, the workaround is to remove the trailing slash from the LOCATION. Once the fix has been rolled out, the trailing slash will work again, as it should.

@Theo thanks - btw I just today found your Athena guide, very good info regarding semi-undocumented "symlink tables", nice work.

The location is being set incorrectly, and should not include a trailing /.
Verify this by checking aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/path/table1/ --recursive. If you see a key with //, such as s3://my-bucket/path/table1//metadata/..., you have encountered this problem. The // is a helpful indication that you've included an extra /.
Simply create the table without the trailing / in the location.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (`col1` string, `col2` string) 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/path/table1'
TBLPROPERTIES ('table_type'='ICEBERG', 'format'='parquet')


I presume this took you a while to troubleshoot, eh? Thanks for sharing!

@JohnRotenstein only a couple of hours ':-D but I have a few years of Athena experience, so kind of familiar with how picky it can be about specifiying properties.
